# Angular2 Service exposing an Observable collection that updates every second

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a Random Data Service, that I would like to expose an       observable array of XyPoint objects. It should initially be populated with an initial point and then every second push another point onto it

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs/Observable';


import { NamedPoint } from '../types/chart';


@Injectable()
export class RandomDataService {

    data: Observable<Array<XyPoint>>
    constructor() {

        this.data = new Observable((observer) =>{
            observer.next(this.getPoint())
            setInterval(
                observer.next(this.getPoint()), 1000
            );
        })
    }

    getPoint() {
        let p = new XyPoint()
        p.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
        return p
    }

    getData(): Observable<Array<XyPoint>>  {
        return this.data
    }

}
```

I then want to subscribe to this service in a charting component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RandomDataService } from '../../services/random.data.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'basic-chart',
    providers: [RandomDataService],
    templateUrl: 'basic.chart.html',
    styleUrls: ['basic.chart.css']

})

export class BasicChart {
    options: Object;
    chart : Object;

    constructor(private randomDataService: RandomDataService){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                width: 700
            },
            series: [{data: []}]
        };
    }

    saveInstance(chartInstance) {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.randomDataService.getData().subscribe(
            value => (this.chart as any).series[0].addPoint(value)
        );

    }

}
```

I was hoping every component that subscribed to the getData() observable would receive the same data, which is why I set data as a member variable, and instantiate it in the constructor.

It works initially as I get two points pushed into my component and then no other messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid mistake, I need to provide a function to setInterval...

```
 this.data = new Observable((observer) =>{
        observer.next(this.getPoint())
        setInterval(
            () => observer.next(this.getPoint()), 1000
        );
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you're trying to do, but I think you might want continuously new points in your observable.

The problem with your code is, that it emits one point and one with a delay after 1000ms and the observable stays open.

```
this.data = new Observable((observer) =>{
        observer.next(this.getPoint())
        setInterval(
            observer.next(this.getPoint()), 1000
        );
    })
```

You could use this code instant, which produces one point each 1000ms.

```
this.data = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .timeInterval()
  .pluck('interval')
  .map(() => this.getPoint());
```